How to update/set SameSite value from “Strict” to "Lax" in chrome, edge, safari browser?
How to update/set SameSite value from “Strict” to "Lax" in chrome, edge, safari browser?
The below answer is outdated
How to disable same site policy in Chrome?
No option available as mentioned below
How to disable same site policy in Chrome?

It is unclear what exactly you want to update. But if you want to relax the recently tightened rules regarding cookie handling, you are sacrificing state-of-the-art web security (--disable-web-security).

I am intending to change the SameSite from Strict to Lax to run some vulnerability checks.

Have you searched the Chrome Web Store for extensions that allow such manipulation of cookie attributes?

Not yet. Do you suggest I should be? If so any specific extension you would recommend?

For Edge and Chrome, previous flag options are all removed, so for now you can try --disable-web-security for test. Remember to use --user-data-dir at the same time and kill all Edge/Chrome processes before launching with these switches.
Not quite sure about Safari, but you may refer to this thread.
